# Can you check if a gps coordinate is inside a gps polygon in R?

Tags: r, geojson

I'm trying to determine if a specific gps coordinate is within a gps spatial polygon.

My gps coordinate is being outputted from the `geocode` function from the **ggmap** library and the spatial polygons are being read from a GeoJSON file using `readOGR`.

So far I've found pieces of what I'm looking for in the sp and maptools library but no specific functions...any suggestions ?

Comment: The high-level ?over or the low-level ?point.in.polygon is what you are after.

Comment: or `over`. data wld be nice tho

Comment: In case you're dealing with projected coordinate systems, `gIntersection` from the **rgeos** package should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that I solved using the `over()` function from the `sp` package. The key was making sure that both the list of GPS points and the loaded shapefile are in the same CRS:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38151918/creating-a-buffer-around-a-geographic-point-and-then-checking-whether-a-list-of